# assign values to column based on two other columns in python

Tags: python

I have two columns retweet and mention like this

```
retweet              mention

RT @CritCareMed:    
                     @CellCellPress
RT @CritCareMed:     @mother
RT @gvwilson:           
RT @sciencemagazine:        
RT @MHendr1cks:      @nucAmbiguous
                     @air
```

I want a new column based on whether it's a retweet or mention and assign M in the row of new if it's a Mention else assign R. If both mention and retweets are present the row should have the value M,R. so the end result should be like

```
 retweet                mention             Type

RT @CritCareMed:                              R
                        @CellCellPress        M
RT @CritCareMed:        @mother               R,M
RT @gvwilson:                                 R
RT @sciencemagazine:                          R
RT @MHendr1cks:         @nucAmbiguous         R,M
                        @air                  M
```

What I'm doing right now is something like

```
df = df.assign(Type=np.where(df.retweet.isnull(), 'M','R'))
```

but it's giving me result

```
             retweet             mention        Type  
      RT @CritCareMed:             NaN           R  
                 NaN       @CellCellPress        M  
       RT @CritCareMed:         @mother          M  
          RT @gvwilson:             NaN          R  
   RT @sciencemagazine:             NaN          R  
        RT @MHendr1cks:   @nucAmbiguous          M  
                  NaN           @air             M
```

where the 3rd and 6th row should have type R,M but it's just giving me M ( as expected from code). How can I modify the code to get the above results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another condition for check another column:

```
df = df.assign(Type=np.where(df.retweet.isnull(), 'M',
                    np.where(df.mention.isnull(), 'R','R, M')))
print (df)
                retweet         mention  Type
0      RT @CritCareMed:             NaN     R
1                   NaN  @CellCellPress     M
2      RT @CritCareMed:         @mother  R, M
3         RT @gvwilson:             NaN     R
4  RT @sciencemagazine:             NaN     R
5       RT @MHendr1cks:   @nucAmbiguous  R, M
6                   NaN            @air     M
```